# Why is 'Data Type' not defined on my custom field?

Tags: custom-field, data-types

[image]

Why is datatype not defined on my custom field (circled below)? And how can I define it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are actually standard fields. There appears to be a "glitch" or mistake by salesforce that's causing the datatype to be displayed in the Field Name column. It's the same in my dev org.

The Field Names values ought to be:

1. Salutation
2. FirstName
3. LastName

And the Datatype for these are

1. Picklist
2. Text(40)
3. Text(80)

You can't define or edit the metadata of these standard fields.